# symfony 3 locale не переадресовывает

Tags: symfony3, locale

Активировал translator

## config.yml

```
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ['en', 'ua', 'ru'] }
    default_locale: 'ua'
```

## parameters.yml

```
locale: ua|ru|en
```

## routing/yml

```
front:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
            _locale: '%locale%'
```

Страницы с локалью открываются. Если же ввести просто / без локали то No found route. Как я понимаю не отрабатывает default_locale. Как настроить чтобы перенаправляло на дефолтную локаль?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
front:
     resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
     prefix: /{_locale}
     requirements:
          _locale: '%app.locales%'
```

это рабочий вариант. 
    `app.locales: ua|ru|en`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете настроить локаль по дефолту
Допустим:

```
front:
resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
prefix: /{_locale}
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index, _locale: ua }
requirements:
        _locale: '%locale%'
```

**Обновлено**
Так же можете использовать [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://coderwall.com/p/eiqd_g/symfony2-the-translation-miracle)